# How to convert a 2-D list (type is DataFrame)?

Tags: python

I have 3 dataframe in list

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data1 = [['A',0],['B',0],['C',1]]
Data1 = pd.DataFrame(data1,columns=['Strategy','Weights'])

data2 = [['A',0],['B',1],['C',0]]
Data2 = pd.DataFrame(data2,columns=['Strategy','Weights'])

data3 = [['A',0],['B',1],['C',0]]
Data3 = pd.DataFrame(data3,columns=['Strategy','Weights'])

AA = []
AA.append(Data1)
AA.append(Data2)
AA.append(Data3)
```

I want to convert like the following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQM6H.png
can someone help me finish it ? and is there an easier way to do it ?thank you very much

Comment: Please don't upload screenshots of text/code/errors

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

use `df.concat(<listOfDataframe>)` to combine multiple dataframe. i.e.

```py
AA = pd.concat([Data1,Data2,Data3],ignore_index=True)
```

**Edit**

If you want to make new dataframe, the easier way to define it, IMO, is:

```
df = {
    'A':[0,0,0],
    'B':[0,1,0],
    'C':[0,1,0]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```